# Can multiple zip file entries be active using ZipOutputStream class?

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I am trying to use DotNetZip open source library for creating large zip files.

I need to be able to write to each stream writer part of the data row content (see the code below) of the data table. Other limitation I have is that I can't do this in memory due to the contents being large (several giga bytes each entry).

The problem I have is that despite writing to each stream separately, the output is all written to the last entry only. The first entry contains blank. Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this issue?

```
static void Main(string fileName)
{
    var dt = CreateDataTable();

    var streamWriters = new StreamWriter[2];

    using (var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(fileName)))
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            var entryName = "file" + i + ".txt";
            zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entryName);
            streamWriters[i] = new StreamWriter(zipOutputStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        }

        WriteContents(streamWriters[0], streamWriters[1], dt);

        zipOutputStream.Close();
    }
}

private DataTable CreateDataTable()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("col1"), new DataColumn("col2"), new DataColumn("col3"), new DataColumn("col4") });

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            row[j] = j * 1;
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return dt;
}

private void WriteContents(StreamWriter writer1, StreamWriter writer2, DataTable dt)
{
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
    {
        writer1.WriteLine(dataRow[0] + ", " + dataRow[1]);
        writer2.WriteLine(dataRow[2] + ", " + dataRow[3]);
    }
}
```

**Expected Results:**

Both file0.txt and file1.txt need to written.

**Actual results:**

Only file1.txt file is written all content. file0.txt is blank.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the expected behaviour according to the [docs](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/en/examples/Ionic.Zip/ZipOutputStream/PutNextEntry/php-zipoutputstream-putnextentry-method-examples.html)

> If you don't call Write() between two calls to PutNextEntry(), the first entry is inserted into the zip file as a **file of zero size**. This may be what you want.

So to me it seems that it is not possible to do what you want through the current API.

Also, as [zip file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) is a continuous sequence of zip entries, it is probably physically impossible to create entries in parallel, as you would have to know the size of each entry before starting a new one.

Perhaps you could just create separate archives and then combine them (if I am not mistaken there was a simple API to do that)

Comment: Eugene, when you say combine archives, are you asking me to create each txt file as a zip and combine then? If so, then I would have zip instead zip, which will not work for us since we are creating files for our customers.

Comment: @hemalmehta I mean that you create separate archives instead of separate entries and then combine them into a single resulting archive that you can send to your client.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand "separate archives instead of separate entries". Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @hemalmehta I mean by creating two instances of the `ZipOutputStream` instead of two `NextEntry`s. And then creating a single archive from those two archive files.

Comment: The whole idea behind directly writing entries to the zip file (instead of first creating the entries and then archiving) is to gain performance. But an alternative you provided sounds interesting and might give me the performance I need. I will research on your solution, but in the meantime if you have the code snippet or the doc, can you point me?